# Eliminar registro de BD con PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos

Buenas, tengo una pequeña consulta a ver si alguien puede ayudarme.

Tengo una tabla que hace conexión a mi base de datos y trae los registros, y ahora necesito que en mi tabla, en cada registro, haya un botón de borrar registro. El botón lo tengo creado como muestro en la siguiente imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy empezando en PHP y no se muy bien como hacerlo

Gracias

Edito: Actualizo la información con el código de la pagina php donde se muestra la tabla

```html
<?php
 require_once 'conexion.php'; //Esto me conecta con la BD
 
  $result;

  $conn = dbConnect();

  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM avisos';

  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  $rows = $result->fetchAll();
 
  ?>

  <table border="1">
 <!--Comprobar si se ha iniciado sesion-->
  <?php
  session_start();
  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
   echo "Has iniciado sesion como ".$_SESSION['username'];
  }else{
   header("location: index.php");
  }
   ?>
   <thead>
    <tr>
         <th>Averia / Pedido</th>
         <th>Estado</th>
         <th>Observaciones</th>
         <th>Borrar/modificar</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <?php
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
   ?>
    <tr>
         <td><?php echo $row['averia']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['estado']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['observaciones']; ?></td>
         <td>
           <a href="#" class="btn" onlick=""></a>
         </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Muestra la tabla sql que tienes para las averías. Lo normal suele ser que el click del boton borrar llame a una acción con verbo Delete con el id de esa avería. En dicha acción haces un Delete from tabla where id=

Comment: Hola Alejandro, podrías subir tus códigos que utilizas para imprimir los resultados? De forma que en base a ello podamos darte una mano :)

Comment: Hola! Acabo de actualizar la pregunta con el código, espero que me podáis echar un cable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo explicare de una forma simple ya que veo que estas aprendiendo.

Una forma en como puedes hacer lo es creando un link que contenta el id del registro. Así solo tendrás que obtener el id utilizando `$_GET['id']` y buscas el registro por ese id y lo eliminas.

En tu button editalo y agrega el link y especificándole la url:

```
<td>
  <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/index.php?eliminar='. echo $row['id'] ?> " class="btn" onlick=""></a>
</td>
```

La url final seria asi: `http://localhost/nombreApp/index.php?eliminar=numeroIdRegistro`.

Entonces ahora, solo tienes que averiguar si el parámetro `eliminar` fue enviado a tu pagina por medio a la url de la siguiente manera:

```
require_once 'conexion.php'; //Esto me conecta con la BD

$result;
$conn = dbConnect();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM avisos';


    if(isset($_GET["eliminar"]))
    {
        // eliminas el registro
        $conexion->query("DELETE FROM tabla WHERE id = ". $_GET["eliminar]);
    }

    //...
```

Todo esto ocurren la misma pagina. Lo unico que se agrego fue el link y la condicion para eliminar.

Lo correcto de hacer enviar el registro por POST, y asi evitar que elimien registro intencionalmente pero como solo es un ejemplo, creo que puedes comenzar con eso.

Aqui la documentacion para [`$_SERVER["SEVER_NAME"]`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) y [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) en caso de que necesites mas informacion.

Answer (score 0):

De la misma forma en que vas asociando los campos de tu consulta a la tabla HTML, debes de asociar el ID de la tabla de tu BD al botón Eliminar: 
`<a href="ruta/archivo.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" class="btn" ><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></a>`

Una opción que puedes emplear es crear un archivo PHP aparte con la definición de la función que se encargará de eliminar el registro en BD; luego de ello, en la propiedad href del HTML '', definirás la ruta donde se encuentra el archivo que creaste y enviarás el parámetro por el método GET (esto se logra con el concatenación de la ruta del archivo, más el signo '?', más la pareja variable=valor).

De esta manera solo tendrás que validar la variable 'id' esté definida y proceder con la eliminación del registro.